# How to use Request.Form to get data from a TextBox in previous page

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, webforms, http-post

I have in page1.aspx webform:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPassCode1" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnTakeTest1" Text="Go to page 2" PostBackUrl="page2.aspx" />
```

So in page2.aspx, I am trying to retrieve the value of `txtPassCode1`, but I don't know how to find it, so I find this code and put it in Page_Load event of page2.aspx code behind, I think basically it displays all POST data from the page1 so I put "-END-" at the end of each Request.Form and display it to a label.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack && Request.RequestType == "POST")
            {
                if (Request.Form != null && Request.Form.Keys.Count > 0)
                {
                    string[] keys = Request.Form.AllKeys;
                    for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
                    {
                        lblPOST.Text = lblPOST.Text + keys[i] + ": " + Request.Form[keys[i]] + " -END- <br>";
                    }                  
                }
            }
        }
```

Let say I entered `1234` in page1 and hit the button, now I am in page2.aspx and I get this:

```
__EVENTTARGET: -END- 
__EVENTARGUMENT: -END- 
__VIEWSTATE: YznkkVzGlJ8TtCKM2Vzx7+DEhiSoaItNvqFaqJKJYPoMTZu7jerq3btXp1r0iob13dEaKV1fSheRySmdCl69U5KRukE4bi2gD68nYOoj0f93ysiTufpvcr4j1t09lMDwjfuQDmVuJqrDlyzEffG+IkOQfdNEn1sAukVwGBwzCGI= -END- 
ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContent$txtPassCode1: 1234-END- 
ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContent$btnTakeTest1: Take this test -END- 
ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContent$txtPassCode2: -END- 
__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR: 22DEEF5F -END- 
__PREVIOUSPAGE: OQ8E2uts0p1smCGF7aTw5vs7Ykqr-CAG0J7QCt87boTAs4TxBB2hkHCK_tPL2nCs45bS9uR7NMxjva1XFW7DDI4_CO2Mt84c8cQu_1Yo1gDenS9hrXC5wlh3iaO-Ftv_0 -END- 
__EVENTVALIDATION: LpMm3Lf2/xeGRstUHMr5WL79abGTpD92nJ/Ltwjsluwt0J7CmS72WqREhKn4x4jz8zvliCoBOxOAc8VhdKHRYajTycLpjxwSu9iEEWR92JvTYsHvKU9qCq1Z95thv0y9TeUW0mHMRqfOA8Pcd4cpYEL7oT2Iq+l+p2JiDFTTyr8yC28WtWj+E1vP018j3+qt -END-
```

So I can see the 4th one it says: `ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContent$txtPassCode1: 1234-END-`
=> `1234` is what I want. How do I retrieve only this value?

I test 
`lblPOST.Text = Request.Form["ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContent$txtPassCode1"];` and it works but will  `ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContent$txtPassCode1` always stay the same or it will change?

Comment: You can get the same as `txtPassCode1.UniqueID`, but yeah it should be the same. It will be changed if controls order is changed (e.g. ctl00 is first control. If order changes, then it will be ctl01). And in theory it might be changed in some never .Net versions. You can save UniqueID from PreviousPage in session, and then reuse it

Comment: I don't want to use Session, otherwise I just put the value from textbox to session and not to worry about POST or ID or anything else really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PreviousPage` property allows you to retrieve the data of the source page from the destination page.

In page1, you can define a `Password1` public property:

```
public string Password1
{
    get { return txtPassCode1.Text; }
}
```

Assuming that the class name of the page1 form is `Page1`, you can do this in the `Page_Load` of page2:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page1 source = PreviousPage as Page1;
    if (source != null)
    {
        string password = source.Password1;
        ...
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

In order to get it from the Request.Form, the mangled ID could be split in its various "parts". The following method can return the correct value if the control is the only one in the form with the given name (meaning that no naming container, like a GridView row or a ListView item, has another control with the same ID):

```
string password = GetPreviousPageControlValue("txtPassCode1");

private string GetPreviousPageControlValue(string ctlId)
{
    foreach (string key in Request.Form.AllKeys)
    {
        string[] tokens = key.Split('$');
        if (tokens[tokens.Length - 1] == ctlId)
        {
            return Request.Form[key];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

This method could be expanded to accept an array of control IDs as arguments, and testing if the sequence of IDs is matched by the last "tokens" of the key. That would allow to find controls in containers.

Comment: So is there anyway to utilize the `Request.Form` instead of finding control though `PreviousPage `?

Comment: I see what you did there. One last question, (you can just answer in comment section or add to the answer): I want to do some passcode validations in `page1` before moving to `page2`, but to do so I can't use `PostBackUrl` but a onlick event instead, then I use `Respond.Redirect("page2.aspx);`. Will `PreviousPage ` or  `Request.Form` still work or they will become `null`?

Comment: After the `Response.Redirect`, `PreviousPage` is null and I don't get the data in `Request.Form`. But since you control the redirect, you could append a query string: `Response.Redirect("page2.aspx?pwd=...")`. I assume that the password value would have to be encoded and/or encrypted. Or you could use `Session`... :-)

Comment: On the other hand, if the password was validated on the client side with a `RegularExpressionValidator`, the postback would happen only when the password is correct. That would allow you to use the `PostBackUrl` property.